# joining two columns sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

world!
I'm currently stuck on this problem where i want to join two columns and run the select statement of the two, but i'm getting errors; these are the columns i want to join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM owner_name.table_name ORDER BY column_name;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT count(column_name) OVER (partition by column_name) Amount from owner_name.table_name order by column_name);
```

where in the second, for every row, i count how many equal rows i have for each value.

the two columns values:
[first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMe2M.png)
[second column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbZC1.png)

i dont know how to have both of them next to each other as a normal select statement:
SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table;

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to use an analytic function for this as you will find the `COUNT` for all the rows and then use `DISTINCT` to discard rows which involves lots of unnecessary calculation.

Instead, it is much more efficient `GROUP BY` the `column_name` and then aggregate so that you only generate a single row for each group to start with:

```sql
SELECT column_name,
       COUNT(column_name) AS amount
FROM   owner_name.table_name
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       column_name,
       COUNT(column_name) OVER (PARTITION BY column_name) Amount 
FROM owner_name.table_name 
ORDER BY column_name;
```